# Hidden folder without a dot at the start

Tags: finder, macos

On any unix machine, Mac included, files and folders with dots at the start are normally invisible. However, it seems that the Mac has it's own type of hidden folder.

If I enable showing hidden files in Finder (`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`), there are 70 dotfiles in my home directory. However, there are two hidden folder without dots: `Trash` and `Library`. In the root directory, there are several (`lost+found`, `bin`, `cores`, etc…).

Is it possible to make one of these folders that is hidden in Finder while keeping it's path the same (AKA not adding a dot)? I use a utility that needs a `~/tmp` folder, and I'd love to hide it in finder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `chflags`

To hide a file from Finder

```
chflags hidden /Path/To/File
```

To unhide:

```
chflags nohidden /Path/To/File
```

Comment: Also, the `ls -lO` command will show file flags, including the hidden flag.

Comment: does hiding from Finder different from it's access via terminal?? Currently, I have a file .DS_Store in a folder on my desktop and it is hidden if I access it via Finder but not when I do `ls` in terminal.

Comment: You cannot hide files from the terminal commands.